# Bootstrap grid - change the order in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap row with four `.col-md-6` divs. So normal screens shows as two sections like this.

[image]

When you are switched to mobile, it change it's order to a single column( shows 4 divs under the each div). I have used two colors for divs. First div has a white background color and second div has a black background color like that. Let's see how it looks like on mobile. The first row second div has a black background and the second row first div has a black background so it's showing two black background color div merged way! How can I fix this or is there any available boostrap's `pull` `push` methods for doing things like this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's [Column Re-Ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) classes to achieve this as follows:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.white,
.black {
  height: 200px;
}

.white {
  background: white;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 white"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 black"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 white"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 black"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did this but it change the order on normal version also.

Comment: @MarkNsu Please apply classes carefully as shown in above snippet or provide a fiddle, I'll try to figure out mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using media query..

```
.div-1,.div-4 {
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
}

.div-2,.div-3 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .div-1,.div-3 {
     background-color: white;
     color: black;
 }
 .div-2,.div-4 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
 }
}
div {
   height: 150px;
}
```

Working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/pranjalp34/x2w38hje/

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the order of the `.col-md-6` divs the same

(ie. Software Development, Web Solutions, Hardware Solutions, Network Solutions)

check to see if you have something like the following:

```
.software-development,
.network-solutions {
color: rgb(0,0,0); /* or #000000 or #000 */
background-color: rgb(255,255,255); /* or #ffffff or #fff */
}

.web-solutions,
.hardware-solutions {
color: rgb(255,255,255); /* or #ffffff or #fff */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* or #000000 or #000 */
}
```

If you have, then simply swap the `color` and `background-color` styles of `.hardware-solutions` and `.network-solutions` in the `@media` queries for mobile.

Comment: I did it and had with problem with my header icon on that div. Because I need to change the icon also

Comment: Ah. Yes, I can see that would be an issue. If you don't change the order of the divs, you'll need two more (negative-image) icons as well.